# Trouble displaying text in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two files: groundup.xml and groundup.xslt.

groundup.xml:

```
<content>
  <root>
    <housing_option_name>The first name</housing_option_name>
    <housing_option_headline>Live under a desk</housing_option_headline>
    <housing_option_address>Kinda behind the Shell gas station</housing_option_address>
    <include_description>true</include_description>
    <description_images>/uploadedImages/RecSports/Intramural_Sports/Photos/Basketball 055.jpg</description_images>
    <description_images>/uploadedImages/StudyAbroad/Slideshow/Adamwood.jpg</description_images>
    <room_types_and_layouts>Here you can sleep. Here you eat.</room_types_and_layouts>
    <include_virtual_room_tour>false</include_virtual_room_tour>
    <include_photos>true</include_photos>
  </root>
  <root>
    <housing_option_name>A real housing option</housing_option_name>
    <housing_option_headline>where fun comes to multiply</housing_option_headline>
    <housing_option_address>
      The address goes here
    </housing_option_address>
    <include_description>false</include_description>
    <description_images>/uploadedImages/bg_mural_Partner_for_Success.jpg</description_images>
    <room_types_and_layouts>Some text about room types and layouts.</room_types_and_layouts>
    <include_virtual_room_tour>false</include_virtual_room_tour>
    <include_photos>true</include_photos>
  </root>
</content>
```

And groundup.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
      <body>

        <div id="residence_halls">
          <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="content/root">
              <div>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                  <xsl:value-of select="translate(housing_option_name, ' ', '_')"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:value-of select="content/root/housing_option_name"/>
              </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I managed to get the housing_option_name into the id field, however, I'm still trying to get the housing_option_name to display as text in the final html. Right now I just see a blank screen, but looking at the final source, there are the two divs with ids of housing_option_name, but no text inside the divs.

What am I missing here?

Edit: The final html looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <div id="residence_halls">
      <div id="The_first_name">
      </div>
      <div id="A_real_housing_option">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Took out uls for brevity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <xsl:value-of select="housing_option_name"/>
```

Surely? Since you're already in a for-each on the content/root path?

Comment: Thank you! I'll make yours the accepted answer in nine minutes. :)